# Limit of the function$f(x) = \frac{x-1}{x-x^a}$ in 1

Tags: real-analysis, limits, holder-inequality

I am struggling with the limit of this function :

$$f(x) = \frac{x-1}{x-x^a} $$

as $x$ tends to 1 and $x>1$. The constant $a$ is lower than 1, i.e.,  $a\in] \infty, 1[$.

My guess is that the limit $\lim_{x\rightarrow 1, x>1} f(x) $ exists and is finite.

Could someone proove this (exact limit or upper bound).

Thank you very much !

Comment: Do you know L'Hopital's Rule?

Comment: You can also get this limit by using the definition of derivative of $x^{a}$ at $1$.

Comment: $a\in] \infty, a[$, shouldn't that be $a\in] -\infty, a[$?

Comment: Thank you all, i have edited my post. I will check L'hopital's rule.

Comment: $x=1+t$, then $f(1+t)=\frac{t}{1+t-(1+t)^a}=\frac{t}{1+t-1-at+O(t^2)}=\frac{1}{(1-a)+O(t)}$. Limit is equal $\frac{1}{1-a}$ independently of direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the denominater tends to 0 as $x$ goes to 1 we use L’hôpital’s rule for finding limits. Using L’hôpital’s rule we get $$\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{x-1}{x-x^a}= \lim_{x\to 1}\frac{1}{1-ax^{a-1}}= \frac{1}{1-a}$$ Note that since 1 raised to any power is 1, $\lim_{x \to 1}x^{a-1}=1$.